# System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox instead of the text box value in asp.net c# web forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

output

[image: 1]

Can someone pls help me on this one. User's input from the textbox data should be displayed. But instead, I got this `System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox`

webform1.aspx.cs

```
Response.Redirect("~/CORView.aspx?fname=" + firstname + "&lname=" + surname + "&idnumber=" + userid);
```

webform2.aspx.cs

```
lbl_id.Text = Request.QueryString["idnumber"];
lbl_fname.Text = Request.QueryString["fname"];
lbl_surname.Text = Request.QueryString["lname"];
```

Comment: you need to use coding standards... naming controls...  `txtFirstName`...
`"xxx" + txtFirstName` = `"xxx" + txtFirstName.ToString()`. You need `"xxx" + txtFirstName.Text`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, assuming you have this code:

```
Response.Redirect("~/CORView.aspx?fname=" + 
firstname + "&lname=" + 
surname + "&idnumber=" + userid);
```

If those values "firstname", surname, userid?

Are those variables, or controls?

If they are controls, then you can't pass the WHOLE control, but only the .Text property of such controls.

Thus, you would need something like this:

```
Response.Redirect("~/CORView.aspx?fname=" + 
firstname.Text + "&lname=" + 
surname.Text + "&idnumber=" + userid.Text);
```

Now, in above I would guess that firstnme.Text, and surname.Text are from controls, and the 3rd userid???? If that is a plain jane c# variable, then you might well need this:

```
Response.Redirect("~/CORView.aspx?fname=" + 
firstname.Text + "&lname=" + 
surname.Text + "&idnumber=" + userid.ToString());
```

So, you can't in a simple web URL pass the "text box" object! (boy, would not that be cool or nice??? - but, you can only pass text strings in the URL, and you can't just "pass" the WHOLE text box as a object.

Thus, as a result, you need to pass the .Text properity of those controls in question.

In fact, what you seeing is this:

```
        Label1.Text = "hello world";
        Debug.Print(Label1.Text);
        Debug.Print(Label1.ToString());
```

output:

```
hello world
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label
```

So, if we try to display a label, say in above, then we can't use Label1, but we have to use Label1.Text.

this suggests the compiler should have caught this error, but perhaps someone where in code, you are assigning the variables (as objects) the control object, and not the control.Text value.

Comment: thanks much man, I actually have a template guide and forgot the ".Text" in my controls Very little mistake yet I spend days figuring out this one. Just new on asp.net